# xml serialization specify xmlelement and xmlattribute together

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

Given :-

```
[XmlRoot("Book")]
public class Book
{
   [XmlAttribute]
   public string Title;

   [XmlElement]
   public string Publisher;

   [XmlElement]
   public string PublisherReference;
}
```

When serialized to XML will give

```
<Book Title="My Book">
   <Publisher>Some Publisher</Publisher>
   <PublisherReference>XYZ123</PublisherReference>
</Book>
```

How could I get PublisherReference as an attribute of Publisher - e.g.

```
<Book Title="My Book">
   <Publisher Reference="XYZ123">Some Publisher</Publisher>
</Book>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
[XmlRoot("Book")]
public class Book
{
   [XmlAttribute]
   public string Title;

   [XmlElement]
   public Publisher Publisher;
}

[Serializable]
public class Publisher
{
  [XmlText]
  public string Value;

  [XmlAttribute]
  public string Reference;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that will do it but any way to do without creating new class - just attributes maybe? Not that I want to moon on a stick or anything... ;)

Comment: unfortunately there is no way to do that (as far a i know) without an additional class