# c# Deserialise 2 different XML nodes into one class with using XmlElement attribute

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

In my project I have to deserialise Xml document into class. Document look like this (basic structure):

```
<Document>
    <Ifno>Some info</Info>
    <Client>
        <CilientName>Name</ClientName>
        <ClientAddress>Address</ClientAddress>
    </Client>
    <Shipper>
        <ShipperName>Name</ShipperName>
        <ShipperAddress>Address</ShipperAddress>
    </Shipper>
</Document>
```

In my code i using `System.Xml.Serialization` so can easly add `XmlRoot` and `XmlElement` Attributes to help with deserlialisation. But i have problem with this `ClientInfo` and `ShipperInfo` nodes. My current code look like this :

```
public class Document
{
    [XmlElement("Ifno")]
    public string Information {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("Client")]
    public Client client {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("Shipper")]
    public Shipper shipper{get;set;}
}

public class Client
{
    [XmlElement("ClientName")]
    public string Name{get;set;}
    [XmlElement("ClientAddress")]
    public string Addres{get;set;}
}

public class Shipper
{
    [XmlElement("ShipperName")]
    public string Name{get;set;}
    [XmlElement("ShipperAddress")]
    public string Addres{get;set;}
}
```

This code is ok and it work proper for me. But as you can see we don't need class `Shipper` and `Client` we can replace it with class e.g `Person` (Just example name ) Because we are using same properties. So code would look like :

```
public class Document
{
    [XmlElement("Ifno")]
    public string Information {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("Client")]
    public Person client {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("Shipper")]
    public Person shipper{get;set;}
}

public class Person
{
    [XmlElement( ? )]
    public string Name{get;set;}
    [XmlElement( ? )]
    public string Addres{get;set;}
}
```

But i have no idea how to name Attributes to make this work ?

Have 2 ideas but don't know is this is possible to code.

First add some validation in Attribute like 
`[XmlElement( parentName="Client" ? "ClientName" : "ShipperName"]` but i have no idea how to check for parent name. 
Second idea is also with parent name 
`[XmlElement(parentName + "Name")]`
This should be possible because property name is always `parent + something` but i can't do this.

I'm 100 % sure that this have simple solution but i have no idea what. Any ideas ?

Comment: IMHO, abandon using attribute based xml tags (on the property names) and just write an XDocument to Dto converter.  It saves so much grief in the long run on the "fringe cases".

Comment: One example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498467/parent-children-xml-to-dto-object-model-with-linq

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823544/xml-serialization-specify-xmlelement-and-xmlattribute-together     But I stand by comment to move away from attributes and just write an XDocument-via-Linq-To-Dto converter object instead.

Comment: That will probably solve this issue, but on whole code we are using Attributes based classes in generic service which must inherit base serializer like : ` var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(element.CreateReader());` changing whole construction for one file will be hard